# ajax data doesn't return correct jQuery html object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, str-replace

When I convert html data from my partial view to $(data) it doesn't return jQuery object I was hoping for like:

`console.log($(data))` -> `[#document]`

Instead it returns this:

`console.log($(data))` -> `[#text, <meta charset=​"utf-8">​, #text, <meta name=​"viewport" content=​"width=device-width">​, #text, <title>​</title>​, #text, <link href=​"/​css?v=EY1fW53lN3Ow8WxEYembf-Ji7ogVpt21gpjVWDy8x6c1" rel=​"stylesheet">, #text, <div>​default​</div>​, #text, <div id=​"test-div">​default​</div>​, #text, <script src=​"/​jsv=k_VAvcysGBhwGVVEK9GAtPakb2vjMfaxz2PhpxPuN0I1">​</script>​, #text
]`

When I do raw console log of my data it returns this:

`console.log(data)` ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/css?v=EY1fW53lN3Ow8WxEYembf-Ji7ogVpt21gpjVWDy8x6c1" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>


        <div>default</div>
        <div id="test-div">default</div>

    <script src="/js?v=k_VAvcysGBhwGVVEK9GAtPakb2vjMfaxz2PhpxPuN0I1"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Question 1:** How can I extract `#test-div` from this data?

---

### Update 1

Here is my controler:

```
public ActionResult Index(string pageName, string categorySlug, string itemSlug)
        {

            if (categorySlug != null)
            {
                var category = _db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Slug == categorySlug);
                if (category == null) return Redirect("/");
                ViewBag.Category = category;

                if (itemSlug != null && category.Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Slug == itemSlug) != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.ItemSlug = itemSlug;
                }
                else if (itemSlug != null)
                {
                    return Redirect("/i/" + categorySlug);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.PageName = pageName;
            return View();
        }
```

Here is my routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{pageName}/{categorySlug}/{itemSlug}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", pageName = UrlParameter.Optional, categorySlug = UrlParameter.Optional, itemSlug = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "ClothRent.Controllers" }
            );
```

Index view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    string pageName = ViewBag.PageName;

    ClothRent.Models.Category c = ViewBag.Category;
}
@switch (pageName)
{
    case "info":
        Html.RenderPartial("_Info");
        break;
    case "i":
        Html.RenderPartial("_Category", c);
        break;
    default:
        <div>default</div>
        <div id="test-div">default</div>
        break;
}
```

_Category partial view:

```
@model ClothRent.Models.Category
@{
    string zveri = "zveri";
    string teli = "teli";
}
@switch (Model.Slug)
{
    case "zveri":
        @zveri
        break;
    case "pasaku-teli":
        @Html.Partial("_Teli", Model);
        break;

}
```

How does it work:

1. I access trough url `/i/category/` and it returns `/home/index` with appropriate partial view data, see how I acquire partial view above.
2. Then if user wants he will proceed browsing website, but instead of reloading page I want to do htmlPushState in witch case I will make ajax call to specific controlers and will extract data I need for the next content I will show.

---

### Update 2

**Question 2:** Is there a way I render returned data from ajax call only with JavaScript, so that I wouldn't need to write an API for ajax calls exclusively?

---

### Update 3

Thanks all for the answers I will surely in future make api for exclusive ajax calls, but for now as I don't master back-end of my website I found a solution using JS.

**[Posted Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14906141/593958)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem thanks to [Dave A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212341/dave-a) by using this syntax.

`$("#container").load("/i/category/ #test-div")`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand. Would a load filtered by a selector for div test-div do what you want?

```
$("#container").load('/i/category/').('#test-div');
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to show me, but I don't want to load all the html from returned data, I want to load part of that html `#test-div` only, I want to exclude everything else. Problem is I can't convert data to normal $(data) object, as you can see it's messed up...

Comment: I want to get `<div id="test-div">default</div>` only.

Comment: Are you sure it's correct syntax? Because my chrome console shows it's incorrect...

Comment: @skmasq have to admit i didn't test it. the concept I'm sure of and syntax seemed right. I'd have to create my own test case to work out chinks.

Comment: @skmasq, I think i finally understand. Again this is untests, but adjusted my answer. It's a selector on data.